# Why is my background task used to send notification based on outcome of a network call not firing at all?

Tags: ios, swift, background-task

I am trying to create a background task to send various notifications at various points in the day, and each of them require a network to check if the notification should be sent. I have tested the API, and I know it works. But when I try to upload my app to my phone, nothing happens (I know because my API logs never show any requests, and I never get notifications when I should). I followed [this video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10142/) and read this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/using_background_tasks_to_update_your_app), but for some reason, the task never seems to schedule/fire.

Here is the related code:

Network call:

```
func checkValue(value: String, hours: Int) async -> Bool {
        // Build url
        var urlString = MY_URL + "/Notification"
        urlString += "?value="+value+"&hours="+String(hours)
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            print("Error: Something wrong with url.")
            return false
        }

        // build full request
        let urlRequest: URLRequest = {
            var request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10)
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
                "Token": API_KEY
            ]
            return request
        }()
        
        // make request
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: SHOULD_SEND)
        config.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true
        
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
//            let (data, response) = try await session.data(for: urlRequest)
        let (data, response) = await withTaskCancellationHandler {
            try! await session.data(for: urlRequest)
        } onCancel: {
            let task = session.downloadTask(with: urlRequest)
            task.resume()
        }
    
        // ensure success
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
            // handle if not 200
            print("Notification response not 200")
            return false
        }

        //assign value
        return try! JSONDecoder().decode(Bool.self, from: data)
    
    }
```

Background Task related code:

```
struct NotificationConfig: Equatable {
    var id: String
    var type: NotificationType // just a string
    var times: [Int]
    var hours: Int
    var title: String
    var body: String
}

var notifications: [NotificationConfig] = [ // desired notifications ]

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        LandingView()
    }.backgroundTask(.appRefresh(SCHEDULE_DAILY_NOTIFICATIONS)) {
        let nextHour = scheduleAppRefresh()
        if nextHour != -1 {
            let times = buildMap()
            
            for notif in times[nextHour] ?? [] {
                let check = makeCheck(notification: notif)
                if await check() {
                    self.sendNotification(notif: notif)
                }
                
            }
        }
    } .backgroundTask(.appRefresh("shouldSend")) {
        let nextHour = scheduleAppRefresh()
        if nextHour != -1 {
            let times = buildMap()
            
            for notif in times[nextHour] ?? [] {
                let check = makeCheck(notification: notif)
                if await check() {
                    self.sendNotification(notif: notif)
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}

func scheduleAppRefresh() -> Int {
    let nextHour = getNextNotifIndex()
    if nextHour == -1 {
        print("OOPS")
    }
    
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let timeZone = TimeZone.current
    
    var dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents(in: timeZone, from: Date())
    dateComponents.hour = nextHour
    dateComponents.minute = 0
    dateComponents.second = 0
    
    guard var desiredTime = calendar.date(from: dateComponents) else {
        return -1
    }

    // if not in future, add a day
    if desiredTime.compare(Date()) == .orderedAscending {
        desiredTime = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: desiredTime)!
    }
    
    let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: SCHEDULE_DAILY_NOTIFICATIONS)
    request.earliestBeginDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: -1, to: desiredTime)!
            
    do {
        try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
    } catch {
        print("Could not schedule app refresh: \(error)")
    }
    
    return nextHour
}

func buildMap() -> [Int: [NotificationConfig]] {
    var times = [Int: [NotificationConfig]]()
    
    for notif in self.notifications {
        for time in notif.times {
            if times[time] != nil {
                times[time]!.append(notif)
            } else {
                times[time] = [notif]
            }
        }
    }
    
    return times
}
    
func getNextNotifIndex() -> Int {
    let timers = buildMap()
    let now = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let timeZone = TimeZone.current
    
    for hour in timers.keys.sorted() {
        var dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents(in: timeZone, from: now)
        dateComponents.hour = hour
        guard let thisTime = calendar.date(from: dateComponents) else {
            continue
        }
        
        if thisTime.compare(now) == .orderedSame || thisTime.compare(now) == .orderedDescending {
            return hour
        }
    }
    
    return -1
}
    
func makeCheck(notification: NotificationConfig) -> () async -> Bool {
    return {
        return checkValue(value: notification.type, hours: notification.hours, meal: meal)
    }
}
        
// Function to send a notification for a specific hour
func sendNotification(notif: NotificationConfig) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in
        if granted {
            print("Notification authorization granted")
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = notif.title
            content.body = notif.body
            content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
            
            let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
            
            let identifier = "notification_\(notif.times[0])_\(notif.id)"
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
            
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error scheduling notification for hour: \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("Notification scheduled successfully")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for the code dump, but I have no idea why it's not working. I followed the steps in the documentation, and set up my app settings (including the Permitted background task scheduler identifiers in Info.plist), but it never even reaches the inside of the .backgroundTask Scene Modifier (using debugger with breakpoints, never stop anywhere in the background task function. A lot of the other helper functions have been tested and should work, but I included them just in case. What could be causing this to happen, and what are steps I could take to debug background tasks? This is my first time using them, and all help would be appreciated.

Are there any further steps to set up background tasks than the developer docs that need to be taken? Perhaps on the device, not in XCode on the project?

Comment: Using "sentinel" values like `-1` isn't very "Swifty". Rather, simply have your functions return an `Int?` and return `nil` instead of -1.   The you get to say `guard let nextHour = scheduleAppRefesh() else { return }`

Comment: And `return try! ...` is asking for a crash. If your app crashes in the background it is even less likely to be get background time.

Comment: You need to call `scheduleAppRefresh` to schedule your initial background refresh event. Where do you do that?